# View pdf in local drive?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my pc there is a **folder which has pdf files** and now i want to display it according to its names. I have done some codings and **it displays the pdf** also. But after that again **error message appears saying "Can't open file. There is an errow with the file format"**

This is my code

```
 try
 {
      this.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
      this.Response.TransmitFile(FilePath+name);
      this.Response.End();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     WebMsgBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```

Comment: Then you pdf maybe corrupt. Open them manually one by one to find out which one is corrupted

Comment: Don't do `this.Response.End();`.

Comment: Where do you have place that code ? Maybe there are other data that also send if you have it inside a web form. This must be inside a handler

Comment: @Kilanny it's not corrupted. I checked it manually. Message appears only when i open it using the system.

Comment: @Aristos, It is inside a page load even. This page opens as a response to a linkButton click even

Comment: @user6592730 Probably this is the problem, make a handler and send it, or totally stop further process of the page - but this is not good design anyway, make a handler.

Comment: can you give me a little exple to show how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a handler, say "DownloadDoc.ashx", and use this code:

```
Option Infer On
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services

''' <summary>
''' Return a pdf document.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class DownloadDoc
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Dim srcDir As String = "~/pdfs"
        Dim fileType As String = ".pdf"

        Dim fname = context.Request.QueryString("name")
        Dim actualFile = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath(srcDir), fname & suffix) & fileType

        If File.Exists(actualFile) Then
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & Path.GetFileName(actualFile) & """")
            context.Response.TransmitFile(actualFile)

        Else
            context.Response.Clear()
            context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404
            context.Response.Status = "404 Not Found"
            context.Response.Write("<html><head><title>404 - File not found</title><style>body {font-family: sans-serif;}</style></head><body><h1>404 - File not found</h1><p>Sorry, that file is not available for download.</p></body></html>")
            context.Response.End()

        End If

    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Then you can use an ordinary `<a href="http://www.example.com/DownloadDoc.ashx?name=mypdf">`.

Note that having a ".pdf" extension is forced so that it can't be subverted to download arbitrary files from the server. You could also make sure that only a filename, and nothing enabling directory traversal, is present, just in case the file permissions are not set securely on the server.

Setting `context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"` is the closest you can get to making the browser offer the file for download rather than displaying it.

**Edit**: Ooh, sorry, you wanted C#. I'm sure you'll be able to translate the above.